# Prove that $\mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^t f_s \, dW_s \right] = 0$, for any continuous stochastic process $f_s$

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I am currently trying to prove that
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^t f_s \, dW_s \right] = 0
$$
where $f_s = f(W_s)$ is some continuous bounded stochastic process.

My attempt to do this is as follows:
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^t f_s \, dW_s \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f_{s_i} \cdot \Delta W_{s_i} \right]
$$
where $\Delta W_{s_i} := W_{s_{i+1}} - W_{s_i}$. This is then equal to
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \mathbb{E} \left[f_{s_i} \cdot \Delta W_{s_i} \right]
$$
which I *believe* is then equal to
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( n \cdot \mathbb{E} \left[f_{s_i} \right] \cdot \mathbb{E} \left[ \Delta W_{s_i} \right] \right)
$$
Thus, since $\mathbb{E} \left[ \Delta W_{s_i} \right] = 0$, we have our result.

So my question is as follows:

1. Is this a correct proof (i.e. Have I made any false assumptions)?
2. Could this have been done better?

Comment: What assumptions do you have on $f$? Under reasonable conditions on $f$, the process $M_t := \int_0^t f(s) \, dW_s$ is actually a martingale, and therefore in particular $\mathbb{E}(M_t) = \mathbb{E}(M_0)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Intuitively, your proposal works quite well, especially if you do not require mathematical rigor. If you require so, two comments are:

(1) Specific reasons are necessary for the commutativity of $\mathbb{E}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}$, and

(2) Conditional expectation could be adopted to clarify the expectation of each term of the sum.

Here is a sketch of proof.

Recall the definition of Ito's integral
$$
Y_t=\int_0^tf_s{\rm d}W_s:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f_{s_j}\left(W_{s_{j+1}}-W_{s_j}\right),
$$
where $0=s_0<s_1<\cdots<s_n=t$ forms a partition of $\left[0,t\right]$. Note that the limit hereinabove is in the sense of the existence of some square-integrable $Y_t$ that satisfies
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left(Y_t-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f_{s_j}^n\left(W_{s_{j+1}}-W_{s_j}\right)\right)^2=0,
$$
where $\left\{f_t^n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of random simple function that approximates $f_t$, i.e., $f_t^n\to f_t$ almost surely (guaranteed by the boundedness of $f_t$, or more generally, square-integrability of $f_t$). Denote
$$
Y_t^n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f_{s_j}^n\left(W_{s_{j+1}}-W_{s_j}\right).
$$

With these understandings, our target could be figured out by
$$
\mathbb{E}Y_t=\mathbb{E}Y_t^n+\mathbb{E}\left(Y_t-Y_t^n\right).
$$
Thanks to the vanishing of the last term, i.e. (using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the definition of $Y_t$),
$$
\left|\mathbb{E}\left(Y_t-Y_t^n\right)\right|\le\mathbb{E}\left|Y_t-Y_t^n\right|\le\sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left(Y_t-Y_t^n\right)^2}\to 0,
$$
it suffices to figure out the limit of $\mathbb{E}Y_t^n$.

$Y_t^n$ is a finite sum, for which
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}Y_t^n&=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f_{s_j}^n\left(W_{s_{j+1}}-W_{s_j}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}\left(f_{s_j}^n\left(W_{s_{j+1}}-W_{s_j}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left(f_{s_j}^n\left(W_{s_{j+1}}-W_{s_j}\right)|\mathcal{F}_{s_j}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}\left(f_{s_j}^n\mathbb{E}\left(W_{s_{j+1}}-W_{s_j}|\mathcal{F}_{s_j}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}\left(f_{s_j}^n\cdot 0\right)\\
&=0.
\end{align}
Therefore, $\mathbb{E}Y_t^n\to 0$, for which $\mathbb{E}Y_t=0$ follows immediately as per the reasoning from above.

You may refer to [here](http://www.sta.cuhk.edu.hk/cyyau/course/2013f_rmsc4005/chapter6.pdf) for more detailed steps with regards to this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Would you mind briefly explaining why $\sqrt{\mathbb{E} [Y_t - Y_t^n]^2} \rightarrow 0$ though?

Comment: @MSmith: My pleasure. No problem. This is exactly the definition of Ito integral, from the second equation in my answer. $Y_t^n$ is a shorthand of the finite sum therein. Do let me know if this explanation is not clear at all :-)

Comment: @MSmith: Or in short, $Y_t$ is defined as the limit of $Y_t^n$ in the sense of quadratic mean. That is, if $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(Y_t-Y_t^n\right)^2\right]\to 0$ for some $Y_t$, this $Y_t$ is then _defined as_ the limit of $Y_t^n$. The tricky part lies in that $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(Y_t-Y_t^n\right)^2\right]\to 0$ implies $\mathbb{E}\left(Y_t-Y_t^n\right)\to 0$, so we can use $\mathbb{E}Y_t^n$ to approximate $\mathbb{E}Y_t$.

Comment: To clarify, does the term $f_{s_j}^n$ denote  $f_{s_j}$ to the power of $n$ in the second equation in your answer?

Comment: @MSmith: Sorry for confusing, both $f_t^n$ and $Y_t^n$ indicate the $n$-th term of some sequence. So a less confusing expression should be $f_t^{(n)}$ (resp., $Y_t^{(n)}$). Here we use $f_t^{(n)}$ to approximate $f_t$, i.e., $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_t^{(n)}=f_t$, where each $f_t^{(n)}$ is a [simple function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function).

Comment: @MSmith: For example, let the bounded $f\in\left[a,b\right]$. Then $\left[a,b\right]$ observes a partition as well, say, $a=y_0<y_1<\cdots<y_n=b$. Then $f_t^{(n)}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}y_j\cdot\mathbb{1}_{f_t^{(n)}\in\left[y_j,y_{j+1}\right)}$. You may see that, as the largest mesh size of this partition $\max_i\left\{y_{i+1}-y_i\right\}$ goes to $0$, $f_t^{(n)}$ tends to $f_t$.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I think I've got it now!

Comment: @MSmith: That is great! Thank you for your feedback. Good luck to you :-)